# Bulkloader on Google App Engine: Incorrect credentials or unsupported authentication type (e.g. OpenId)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7

I am getting this error when trying to automatically generate the bulkloader configuration file of my Google App Engine Datastore

```
Authentication Failed: Incorrect credentials or unsupported authentication type (e.g. OpenId)
```

The appcfg.py command I am using is

```
create_bulkloader_config --filename=bulkloader_config.yaml --url=http://APPID.appengine.com/_ah/remote_api --application=APPID
```

on MacOS Mavericks, Python 2.7

Comment: The bulkuploader doesn't support the oauth authentication method; you *have* to use a username / password.

Comment: How should i do it with appcfg ?

Comment: The [original documenation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata) is gone, so it looks as if the functionality is shifting drastically. There is the [wayback archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20140210190351/https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata) still, but that's it.

Comment: is there any alternative to it?

Comment: Not that I could find. Can't even find the new experimental option in the new console either, for that matter!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with

```
appcfg.py download_data --url=http://APP_ID.appspot.com/_ah/remote_api --filename=FNAME
```

What helped was first running

```
appcfg.py update .
```

After running `appcfg.py update`, `download_data` prompted me:

```
Please enter login credentials for APP_ID.appspot.com
Email:
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I use:

```
appcfg.py create_bulkloader_config --url=http://APPID.appengine.com/_ah/remote_api --filename=bulkloader.yaml --application=s~APPID
```

(Note the `s~` prepending your appid.)

Answer (score 1):

Tried all of the above to no avail. What worked for me was doing an update where I pass in the oauth2 flag. Then everything worked fine:

appcfg.py --oauth2 update app.yaml